# Google sheets, remove characters inside a string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a value in a cell like this: '2016-Week 44'

I would like to the output as '2016-44', so how could I do this?

Edit: so I have values like this

'2016-Week 44'
'2016-Week 45'
'2016-December'

If the value does not contain 'week', I want it to return NA or error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd solve it with regular expressions. Assuming the original values are in column A, this would be the expression:

`=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1,"(?i)week"),REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([\d])\-\w+ ([\d])","$1-$2"),"empty")`

`(?i)week` → Pre-condition: empty if not string "week", case insensitive

`([\d])` → First numeric Group ($1)

`\-\w+`  →Character string (-) and not used text (if the word "week" does not appear the function is not processed by the first conditional)

`([\d])` → Second numeric group ($2)

Comment: After investigating this question and testing the solutions, I can confirm that this is the correct question. You only need to change the `empty` keyword for `NA` or `error` to completely fulfill the original statement. Alternatively, if @NewGirl wants a real error (as opposed to a keyword), you can substitute it by a division by zero with `0/0` to create an error.

Answer (score 1):

try simple:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1; "Week "; )
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but any idea how i can combine it with a query?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result?